# Can I get rid of this switch and enum?

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

I am under the impression that this piece of code could be cleaner by somehow utilizing polymorphism, but I can't seem to find a proper way of doing it. I tried using the Visitor pattern but didn't manage to get very far with it.

The "Hero" class that has the switch:

```
public class Hero {
    private Equipment equipment = new Equipment();
    // other fields

    public void equipArmor(Armor armor) {
        findCorrespondingArmorSlot(armor).equipItem(armor);
    }

    private ItemSlot findCorrespondingArmorSlot(Armor armor) {
        switch (armor.getArmorType()) {
        case SHIELD:
            return equipment.offHand;
        case BODY:
            return equipment.body;
        case HEAD:
            return equipment.head;
        case GLOVES:
            return equipment.hands;
        case BOOTS:
            return equipment.feet;
        case BELT:
            return equipment.waist;
        case AMULET:
            return equipment.neck;
        case RING:
            return equipment.finger;
        case TRINKET:
            return equipment.special;
        }
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    public Equipment getEquipment() {
        return equipment;
    }

    // other methods

    public class Equipment {
        public ItemSlot mainHand = new ItemSlot();
        public ItemSlot offHand = new ItemSlot();
        public ItemSlot body = new ItemSlot();
        public ItemSlot head = new ItemSlot();
        public ItemSlot hands = new ItemSlot();
        public ItemSlot feet = new ItemSlot();
        public ItemSlot waist = new ItemSlot();
        public ItemSlot neck = new ItemSlot();
        public ItemSlot finger = new ItemSlot();
        public ItemSlot special = new ItemSlot();
    }

}
```

And some other stuff:

```
public class ItemSlot {
    private static final Miscellaneous EMPTY = new Miscellaneous();

    private Item item = EMPTY;

    public Item getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void equipItem(Item item) {
        unequipItem();
        this.item = item;
    }

    public void unequipItem() {
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            item.addToInventory();
            item = EMPTY;
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (item == EMPTY);
    }
}

public abstract class Item {
    // fields

    public void addToInventory() {
        // code
    }

    // other methods
}

public class Miscellaneous extends Item{}

public class Armor extends Item {
    private ArmorType type;

    public ArmorType getArmorType() {
    return type;
    }

    //other methods
}

public enum ArmorType
{
    SHIELD, BODY, HEAD, GLOVES, BOOTS, AMULET, RING, BELT, TRINKET;
}
```

Comment: Using a Map will solve the issue..

Comment: I wouldn't remove the `enum`. You can iterate through an `enum`. Using this method your `Armor` class can generate itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
public enum ArmorType
{
    SHIELD(){
        public ItemSlot getArmorSlot(Equipment equipment){
            return equipment.offHand;
        } 
    },
    ...

    public abstract ItemSlot getArmorSlot(Equipment equipment);
}
```

Then call:

```
ItemSlot armorSlot = armor.getArmorType().getArmorSlot(equipment);
```

Comment: But is this approach cleaner?

Comment: @Aeailmuawe Yes, it uses polymorphism and makes sure that new enum constants won't be forgotten. If you can refactor your classes so that the armorSlot are not members of Equipment, you might even be able to simplify this, by specifying a member variable in the enum and just set it in the constructor of the enum.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but I can't seem to understand what you mean with "by specifying a member variable in the enum and just set it in the constructor of the enum."

Comment: @Aeailmuawe Enums support constructors and you can the enum constants can pass parameters to the constructor. But on second thought this might not be applicable in your case since ItemSlot is mutable and probably doesn't belong to ArmorType.

Answer (score 2):

How about a HashMap in Equipment Class?

Like this:

```
public HashMap<String, ItemSlot> itemSlots = new ItemSlots HashMap<String, ItemSlot>();
```

Then in your constructor:

```
itemSlots.put("mainHand ", new ItemSlot());
```

You just then have to define a method like this:

```
public ItemSlot getItemSlot(String item) {
  return itemSlots.get(item);
}
```

Finally, your case will be something like:

```
return equipment.getItemSlot(armor.getArmorType());
```

Comment: I'll look into maps. I'm guessing it's possible to have a HashMap<ArmorType, ItemSlot>?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get away from the switch. Remember that enums are but statical guaranteed singletons. So they can have methods. Just do it like the following:

```
public enum ArmorType {
    SHIELD {
        public ItemSlot getItemSlot(Equipment e) { return e.offHand; }
    },
    // ... repeat for all other armor types
    TRINKET {
        public ItemSlot getItemSlot(Equipment e) { return e.special; }
    };

    public abstract ItemSlot getItemSlot(Equipment e);
}
```

Then you can simply call `armorType.getItemSlot(equiment);`.